# Refactoring Rails controller code using the same string as a symbol, instance variable, and attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have the following code in a controller, and I'd like to know the best way to refactor it into one piece.

```
if @country
    if s.address
        s.address.country = @country
    else
        s.address = Address.create(:country => @country)
    end
end

if @state
    if s.address
        s.address.state = @state
    else
        s.address = Address.create(:state => @state)
    end
end

if @zip
    if s.address
        s.address.zip = @zip
    else
        s.address = Address.create(:zip => @zip)
    end
end
```

If there was one variation here I'd do something like

```
    [:country, :state, :zip].each do |location|
        ...
    end
```

but in this case I'm using :country, .country, and @country; what's a better way to take advantage of them having the same 'root' string? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend:

1. Following **thin controller, fat model** best practice and remove all business logic from controller.
2. Use meaningful variable names. What is `s` in your example? If student - why not call it `student`?

Assuming `county` and `state` are text values and not associated fields I would change your code to the following:

**In controller:**

```
student.create_or_update_address(county: @county, state: @state, zip: @zip)
```

**In student.rb** (Or other model if `s` is not student)

```
def create_or_update_address(options)
  address_attributes = options.delete_if { |k, v| v.empty? }

  if address
    address.update_attributes(address_attributes)
  else
    s.address = Address.create(address_attributes)
  end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

```
[:country, :state, :zip].each do |e|
  if v = instance_variable_get("@#{e}")
    if s.address
      s.address.send(e) = v
    else
      s.address = Address.create(e => v)
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This taught me some valuable things, but the other answer solves a deeper problem. Thanks!